# Selenium get_attributed('innerHTML') is converting values with dot to values with comma

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

After I select a tag when I try to get HTML contents. it is converting the values such as 0.102 to 0,102. There are some values like 1,203 they remain the same. but float type is being wrongly converted.

I'm new so I haven't tried much

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.widget-equity-technical-key-data table")
html = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

say a column with values 1,201 and 0.102 expected at least 1201 and 0.102 but the actual output is 1,201 and 0,102

Comment: Can you share HTML code for this css selector `div.widget-equity-technical-key-data table`

Comment: its a different website not mine. [site](https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/equity/DE000A1EWWW0) is the site im trying to scrape i have to select technical figures table and values.

Comment: Can you navigate us to `technical figures table` ?

Comment: can u put image of table from site u want to read ?

Answer (score 0):

post `findElement` method you can use replace method on strings and then perform `assert`

for value 1,201

```
String s1 = s1.replace(',', '');
```

for value 0,102

```
String s1 = s1.replace(',', '.');
```

Comment: I cant do it. As soon as i convert it into html . is gone i cant know which one is decimal and which is whole number. after i convert all i get is 1,201 and 0,102 cant hard code stuff

Comment: don't convert it to HTML, try using direct string after find element and then using get_attribute method.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant *HTML* would have been helpful to debug the issue in a better way. However to retrieve the *innerHTML* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.widget-equity-technical-key-data table"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='widget-equity-technical-key-data']//table"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```